# write numbers in excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

function writing only last numbers exp: [-big number-, 5, 5, 5, 0.03] when it should be like this [-big number-, 1, 1, 1, 0.01]. I think its about this part `workbook.save(path)` but I dont understand where I should put it.

```
def Calc():  
    global path  
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    print(workbook.get_sheet_names())
    sheet = workbook.active
    for i in range (0, 4):
        for A in range (1, 6):
            for L in range (1, 6):
                for n in range (1, 6):
                    for T in np.arange (0.01, 0.04, 0.01):
                        K=A*pow((1-math.exp(-L*T)), n)                  
                        c1 = sheet.cell(row = i+10, column = 1)
                        c1.value=K
                        c2 = sheet.cell(row = i+10, column = 2)
                        c2.value=A
                        c3 = sheet.cell(row = i+10, column = 3)
                        c3.value=L
                        c4 = sheet.cell(row = i+10, column = 4)
                        c4.value=n
                        c5 = sheet.cell(row = i+10, column = 5)
                        c5.value=T
                        workbook.save(path)
    #workbook.save(path)
```

Comment: What EXCEL output do you expect?

Comment: I wrote it in desc: expect [-big number-, 1, 1, 1, 0.01], but have [-big number-, 5, 5, 5, 0.03]

Comment: The ```row = i+10``` in the loop means only row 10,11,12,13,14 will output, in the Answer below, I change the code to output all rows. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change a little of your code, so it can output all rows:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
import math

def Calc():
    path = "./test.xlsx"
    workbook = load_workbook(path)
    print(workbook.get_sheet_names())
    sheet = workbook.active
    # NOTE: change row from 1 to 10
    row = 10
    for i in range (0, 4):
        for A in range (1, 6):
            for L in range (1, 6):
                for n in range (1, 6):
                    for T in np.arange (0.01, 0.04, 0.01):
                        K=A*pow((1-math.exp(-L*T)), n)                  
                        c1 = sheet.cell(row, column = 1)
                        c1.value=K
                        c2 = sheet.cell(row, column = 2)
                        c2.value=A
                        c3 = sheet.cell(row, column = 3)
                        c3.value=L
                        c4 = sheet.cell(row, column = 4)
                        c4.value=n
                        c5 = sheet.cell(row, column = 5)
                        c5.value=T
                        row = row + 1
    workbook.save(path)                 

Calc()
```

Comment: thx, it working, but I thought `row = i+10` will start write number from position row 10 col 1, cos in overal there will be data on the beginig of excel file, with which the code will work

Comment: in the answer, i have changed the start row from 1 to 10~ yes, ```row = i+10``` will start from row 10, but the range of ```i``` is ```0, 1, 2, 3, 4``` in your code, so the values calculated later will override the previous values.